# How to replace single web resources locally?

Tags: redirect, proxy

I am often working with websites to which I have no code access but for which I need to test javascripts, ajax calls and other resources in locally modified versions.

As an example I needed to test a new creative code originally coming from a DoubleClick server. Instead of working directly on DoubleClick and loose a lot of time waiting for my changes to take effect I needed to manipulate a local copy of that javascript resource.

So I changed my /etc/hosts to point the DoubleClick server to localhost where I run a local web server. This way I was able to test a local script instead of the original.

Of course this redirected all resources and not only the one i was interested in what often results in either weird behaviour as resources become unavailable or a lot of effort on my part to make them available.

Is there a way to replace a specific URL by redirecting it to a local file/URL and let all the others from the same origin be untampered?